# Oracle equivalant of MS SQL Date Query

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to run the query below on an Oracle server. I have tried many iterations and a few hours lost so far with no success. What would be the equivalent in Oracle that would Print the result of the equation?

```
Declare @WeekendingDay varchar(10)
Declare @DayNumber int
Declare @InputDate varchar(10)

Declare @conInputDate datetime
Declare @outWeekending datetime
Declare @CovertToInt varchar(10)
/* ------------------------------Inputs ------------------------------ */
/* uncomment the weekending day you want */
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Monday'
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Tuesday'
Set @WeekendingDay = 'Wednesday'
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Thursday'
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Firday'
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Saturday'
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Sunday'

/* Date you want the weekending of */                       
Set @InputDate = '29/12/2016'

/* Yes to convert Date as INT, No for normal date output */
Set @CovertToInt = 'No'

/* --------------------♫♫♫…Start the magical dance…♫♫♫-------------------- */
Set @DayNumber = CASE @WeekendingDay
              WHEN 'Sunday' Then 1
              WHEN 'Monday' THEN 2
              WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 3
              WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 4
              WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 5
              WHEN 'Friday' THEN 6
              WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 7
        END


Set @conInputDate = CONVERT(datetime,@InputDate,103)
Set @outWeekending = DATEADD (dd, case when DatePart (DW, @conInputDate)=@DayNumber then 0 else -1 * DatePart (DW, @conInputDate) + 7 + @DayNumber end ,@conInputDate)

/* ------------------------------Outputs------------------------------*/
If @CovertToInt = 'Yes'
  Begin 
  PRINT convert(int, convert(varchar(10), @outWeekending, 112))
  END

If @CovertToInt = 'No'
  Begin
  PRINT @outWeekending 
  END
```

Oracle Attempt so far

```
Declare
DayNumber Number(6);
InputDate varchar2(10);
conInputDate date;
outweekending date;

BEGIN
DayNumber := 4;
InputDate := '29/12/2016';
conInputdate := to_date(Inputdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
outweekending := DATEADD (dd, case when DatePart (DW, conInputDate)= DayNumber then 0 else -1 * DatePart (DW, conInputDate) + 7 + DayNumber end , conInputDate)

dbms_output.put_line(outweekending);
END
```

Comment: Upvoted for somehow including musical note characters.

Comment: What part of this code is giving you troubles in converting to Oracle? Please post what you've done so far and the piece of code that you were not able to re-write in Oracle

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  (alt 14) in SQL Developer :P

Comment: @Aleksej added my Oracle attempt. Returns error when encountering dbms_output

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen should have removed those :), but it's Alt + 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
    day varchar(20) := 'Wednesday';
    dt date := to_date('29-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy');
    next_dt date;
    convert_to_int varchar(10) := 'No';
begin
    next_dt := next_day(dt - 1, day);
    if convert_to_int = 'Yes' then
        dbms_output.put_line(to_char(next_dt,'yyyymmdd'));
    else
        dbms_output.put_line(next_dt);
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: That works exactly as I wanted it to. Thank you. I will read up on the functions you have used and try to understand it properly, seems much more elegant than the MS SQL I used.